# How can I pass a value (heightmap) from a material shader to the compositor?

Tags: materials, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I need to get either the 2d image data, or material data from a texture node, into the compositor. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please explain further what you want to do. Images and textures can be used directly on the compositor. I would think that you are looking for the MapUV functionality or maybe ID masks, but it would help if you clarified the goal you are after.

Comment: maybe AOVs? They are present in Cycles and now also in Eevee.

Comment: Really what I need is two separate material outputs on the same object, which I can then overlay in the compositor. I think AOV is what I need, but I have yet to figure out how to use them.